# React Native - Nested FlatLists Rendering Exponentially

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nested, react-native-flatlist

This is a head scratcher.

In order to render multiple columns in the sections of a SectionList, it is my understanding that one must render FlatLists within each section. This is because only FlatList supports the numColumns prop.

For some reason, the code below seems to render a FlatList of all items for each item in the given section.

Code:

```
export default class LetterList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let lists = [
        {
          key: "One",
          data: [{letter: 'a'}, {letter: 'b'}]
        },
        {
          key: "Two",
          data: [{letter: 'c'}, {letter: 'd'}, {letter:'e'}]
        }
        {
          key: "Three",
          data: [{letter: 'f'}]
        }
      ]

    return (
      <View key="letterList" >
        <SectionList
          renderItem={({section}) =>
            (
              <FlatList
                data={section.data}
                renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.letter}</Text>}
              />
            )
          }
          renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Text>{section.key}</Text>}
          sections={lists}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Looks like:

```
One
ab
ab
Two
cd
e
cd
e
cd
e
Three
f
```

What could be causing this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to render multiple columns in the sections of a SectionList, it is my understanding that one must render FlatLists within each section. This is because only FlatList supports the numColumns prop.

This assumption is wrong... section list already "creates" the needed lists,
you are not supposed to create a FlatList per section, only align the data the way a SectionList needs it

Please look at the following example provided by the official docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist

Example 1, taken from Link:

```
// Example 1 (Homogeneous Rendering)
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <Text key={index}>{item}</Text>}
  renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
  )}
  sections={[
    {title: 'Title1', data: ['item1', 'item2']},
    {title: 'Title2', data: ['item3', 'item4']},
    {title: 'Title3', data: ['item5', 'item6']},
  ]}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
/>
```

Comment: Yes but how do you achieve a grid layout this way? If you do this and apply flexWrap: wrap, you will receive an error recommending a flatlist with numColumns prop.

Comment: That is correct... jin order to render a section list side way (i.e: like a grid) you must provide a number of desired columns.. if you need this to be dynamic per device (which I guess you probably do)... just calculate the amount of cells that will actually fit into the screen size and set your  `numColumns` accordingly...

Comment: SectionList does not support numColumns. Currently there is no support for SectionList with a grid layout without side effects.

Comment: We are correct... I will update my answer... it's not informative enough.... I do have a solution though it's not a "pretty" one... I needed to have such a behavior for a custom emoji picker I needed to implement... I my solution was to use FlatList with `numColumns`, and then manipulated the data in such a way that there are three kinds of items that render inside the list, "Header" items, "Empty" items and "Section" items. The list then shows one "Header" item with a couple of "Empty" items to fill the row, and all the "Section" items will render correctly below it until the next Header item

Comment: Again... this is not a pretty solution, but if you have defined list that should be shown, it should suffice...

Answer (score -2):

This appears to serve the purpose.

```
  render() {
    let lists = [
        {
          key: "One",
          data: [{letter: 'a'}, {letter: 'b'}]
        },
        {
          key: "Two",
          data: [{letter: 'c'}, {letter: 'd'}, {letter:'e'}]
        },
        {
          key: "Three",
          data: [{letter: 'f'}]
        }
      ]
    console.log("Rendering");
//  console.log(this.props.data);
    listsComponents = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      listsComponents[i] = (
        <View>
          <Text>{lists[i].key}</Text>
          <FlatList
            key={lists[i].key}
            data={lists[i].data}
            numColumns={2}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.letter}</Text>}
          />
        </View>
      )
    }

    return (
      <View>
        {listsComponents}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```